# If $\forall \gamma>0$, $x>1-\gamma$, then $x\geq 1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> If $\forall \gamma>0$, $x>1-\gamma$, then $x\geq 1$?

I am confused about this simple thing. Can you help?

Comment: It is equivalent to $x>\alpha$ for any $\alpha<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume by contradiction $x < 1$. Then there is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $x = 1-\varepsilon$. However, by hypothesis you should have $x > 1-\varepsilon$. Contradiction. Hence $x \ge 1$.